# No scrollbars appear in an autoscrollable form

Tags: delphi

------------------------- ORIGINAL QUESTION -------------------------

Greetings to all Delphi developers! In a Delphi 2006 non MDI application, I create a non-sizeable, autoscrollable, autosizeable form. This is an excerpt from the form's unit:

```
uses Grid;

TGridFrm = class(TForm)
    public
        Grid : TGrid;
        constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent; Asize : TPoint);
end;

implementation

constructor TGridFrm.Create(AOwner: TComponent; Asize : TPoint);
begin
    inherited Create(aowner);
    borderstyle := bsSingle; // users are not allowed to resize the form
    windowstate := wsNormal;
    borderwidth := 0;
    autosize := True;
    autoscroll := True;
    constraints.maxwidth := screen.width - 1;
    constraints.maxheight := screen.height - 1;
    grid := TGrid.Create(asize.x, asize.y, self);
end;
```

Now, TGrid is a custom control with its own canvas of course. This is an excerpt from its unit:

```
TGrid = class (TCustomControl)
    public
        NoOfCellsX,
        NoOfCellsY,
        CellSize : integer;
        procedure SetZoom(z : integer);
        constructor Create(AWidth, AHeight : Integer; AParent : TForm = nil);
end;

implementation

constructor TGrid.Create(AWidth, AHeight : Integer; AParent : TForm = nil);
begin
    inherited Create(AParent);
    Parent := AParent;
    align := alCustom;
    left := 0;
    top := 0;
end;

procedure TGrid.SetZoom(zoom : integer);
begin
    cellsize := zoom * 10 div 100;
    width := noofcellsx * cellsize;
    height := noofcellsy * cellsize;
end;
```

In the form's unit I have arranged things up (through an ApplicationEvents object) so that SetZoom is called with some zoom value, whenever the numeric +/- keys are pressed. The idea behind all this was to have my custom control snap to the upper left corner of the form (with some predefined margin/borderwidth), and have the entire form automatically adjust its size whenever I zoom in or out of the custom control, but never extending beyond the screen limits. It's working, but only up to the point where the scrollbars must become visible: they *never* show up. Since this is an autoscrollable form, aren't they supposed to show up whenever a control inside the form (Grid in this case) gets larger than the constrained form and get out of the way when it gets smaller? I even tried some refactoring by moving SetZoom to the form's class, but to no avail. What am i missing here?

----------------- COMPILABLE CODE ADDED AFTERWARDS ------------------

The project file:

```
program MyApp;

uses
    Forms,
    Grid in 'Source\Grid.pas',
    GridForm in 'Source\GridForm.pas' {GridFrm},
    Main in 'Source\Main.pas' {MainFrm};

{$R *.res}

begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TMainFrm, MainFrm);
    Application.Run;
end.
```

The Main.pas:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls,
    Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
    TMainFrm = class(TForm)
        CreateNewFormButton: TButton;
        procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
        procedure CreateNewFormButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    end;

var
    MainFrm: TMainFrm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
    GridForm;

procedure TMainFrm.CreateNewFormButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var aform : TForm;
begin
    aform := TGridFrm.Create(self, point(15, 15));
    aform.show;
    tgridfrm(aform).grid.SetZoom(100);
end;

procedure TMainFrm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    Action := caFree;
end;

end.
```

The GridForm.pas:

```
unit GridForm;

interface

uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
    Dialogs, Grid, AppEvnts;

type
    TGridFrm = class(TForm)
        ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
        procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
        procedure ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
    private
        TheGrid : TGrid;
    public
        property Grid : TGrid READ TheGrid WRITE TheGrid;
        constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent; ASize : TPoint);
    end;

var
    GridFrm: TGridFrm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TGridFrm.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var keystate : TKeyboardState;
begin
    if not Active then begin exit; end;
    if msg.message = WM_KEYDOWN then
    begin
        getkeyboardstate(keystate);
        case msg.wparam of

            vk_Add : begin // zoom in
                grid.setzoom(grid.zoom + 10);
                handled := True;
            end;

            vk_Subtract : begin // zoom out
                grid.setzoom(grid.zoom - 10);
                handled := True;
            end;

            // other keys down here...

        end;
    end;
end;

constructor TGridFrm.Create(AOwner : TComponent; ASize : TPoint);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
    borderstyle := bsSingle;
    borderwidth := 2;
    autosize := True;
    autoscroll := True;
    constraints.maxwidth := screen.width - 1;
    constraints.maxheight := screen.height - 1;
    visible := False;
    grid := TGrid.Create(asize.x, asize.y, random(800) + 500, self);
end;

procedure TGridFrm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin                
    Action := caFree;
end;

end.
```

And the Grid.pas:

```
unit Grid;

interface

uses
    StdCtrls, SysUtils, Controls, Forms, Graphics, Dialogs;

type
    TGrid = class (TCustomControl)
        Lbl1, Lbl2,
        GridSizeInfoLbl,
        FormSizeInfoLbl,
        WarningLbl : TLabel;

        public
            NoOfCellsX,
            NoOfCellsY,
            SquareSize, // in 1/1000ths of centimeter
            CellSize, // in pixels
            Zoom : integer;
            procedure SetZoom(z : integer);
            constructor Create(x, y, asquaresize : integer; AParent : TForm = nil);
    end;

implementation

uses
    GridForm;

constructor TGrid.Create(x, y, asquaresize : integer; AParent : TForm = nil);
begin
    inherited Create(AParent);
    parent := AParent;
    color := clTeal;
    align := alCustom;
    left := 0;
    top := 0;
    noofcellsx := x;
    noofcellsy := y;
    squaresize := asquaresize;
    Lbl1 := TLabel.Create(self);
    Lbl2 := TLabel.Create(self);
    GridSizeInfoLbl := TLabel.Create(self);
    FormSizeInfoLbl := TLabel.Create(self);
    WarningLbl := TLabel.Create(self);
    with Lbl1 do
    begin
        parent := self;
        caption := 'Size of grid: ';
        width := 55;
        height := 18;
        left := 2;
        top := 1;
    end;
    with Lbl2 do
    begin
        parent := self;
        caption := 'Size of form: ';
        width := 75;
        height := 18;
        left := 2;
        top := 19;
    end;
    with GridSizeInfoLbl do
    begin
        parent := self;
        width := 100;
        height := 18;
        left := 65;
        top := 1;
    end;
    with FormSizeInfoLbl do
    begin
        parent := self;
        width := 100;
        height := 18;
        left := 65;
        top := 19;
    end;
    with WarningLbl do
    begin
        parent := self;
        width := 150;
        height := 18;
        left := 2;
        top := 39;
    end;
end;

procedure TGrid.SetZoom(z : integer);
begin
    zoom := z;
    cellsize := (screen.pixelsperinch * squaresize * zoom) div (1000 * 254);
    width := noofcellsx * cellsize;
    height := noofcellsy * cellsize;

    GridSizeInfoLbl.caption := inttostr(Width) +
        'x' + inttostr(Height) +
        ' (zoom: ' + inttostr(zoom) +
        ', cellsize zoomed: ' + inttostr(cellsize) +
        ', squaresize: ' + inttostr(squaresize) +
        'mm, squares: ' + inttostr(noofcellsx) + 'x' + inttostr(noofcellsy) + ')';
    with tgridfrm(parent) do
    begin
        left := (screen.Width - width) div 2;
        top := (screen.Height - height) div 2;
        FormSizeInfoLbl.caption := inttostr(Width) + 'x' + inttostr(Height) +
        ' (clientarea: ' + inttostr(clientwidth) + 'x' + inttostr(clientheight) + ')';
        if self.width > clientwidth then
            if self.Height > clientheight then
                warninglbl.caption := 'Both scrollbars should appear!'
            else
                warninglbl.caption := 'Horizontal scrollbar should appear!'
        else if self.Height > clientheight then
            warninglbl.caption := 'Vertical scrollbar should appear!'
        else
            warninglbl.caption := 'No scrollbars needed';
    end;
end;

end.
```

Code synopsis: A click on the main form' s button creates an autosizeable form, which in turn creates a child grid of random initial size. Numeric +/- keys make the grid larger or smaller and the form is autosized accordingly, but *no scrollbars ever show up*, no matter how large the grid becomes (the labels I added provide visual feedback).

Comment: AutoSize AND AutoScroll? I would imagine they fight with each other. They both get affected by the exact same thing: controls placed outside its bounds.

Comment: Post compilable code so that we can see if it's the problem or not.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I wrote the code that reproduces the problem. How am I supposed to post it here? Is it OK to post it as an answer to my question or this is against the rules? Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: @JerryDodge I think AutoSize:=True is not "antagonistic" of AutoScroll:=True (or vice versa). It just saves me the trouble of having to manually set the width/height of the form every time SetZoom is called and it works just fine.

Comment: Include a minimal example in the question itself, see [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for updating your code, but it is still not an MCVE. As far as I can tell, your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with this custom grid control, but its container form. The same should apply for *any* control, right? That's the purpose of an MCVE, to eliminate everything which is not actually related to the problem, specifically the "Minimal" part. In the process of creating an MCVE, chances are you will discover your problem yourself, because you won't have loads of irrelevant code to read through.

Comment: Jerry is right. I tried to help since this is your first question but the effort required to reproduce the case takes some of the fun. ;) You could at least use a single form containing also the grid control having defined in the same unit, hence coming up with a single unit ready to copy and paste. Currently the main form serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is twofold.

The first is, as Jerry commented to the question, `AutoSize`. The purpose of autosize is to resize the form such that content is visible. There can be no scrollbars when all content is visible, so clearly the two properties are contradictory.

As such VCL developers have took their precaution. Below is from D2007 source:

```
function TScrollingWinControl.AutoScrollEnabled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not AutoSize and not (DockSite and UseDockManager);
end;
```

As you can see setting `AutoScroll` has no effect when `AutoSize` is set.

You could override this behavior, this is a virtual method, if it wouldn't interfere with the second fold.

Now that you've decided to leave autosize off and calculate and set the required size of your form yourself depending on the workarea size, meet your second problem: alignment of your grid control.

The below is the D2007 code when a vertical scroll bar wants to see if it needs to adjust:

```
  procedure ProcessVert(Control: TControl);
  begin
    if Control.Visible then
      case Control.Align of
        alTop, alNone:
          if (Control.Align = alTop) or (Control.Anchors * [akTop, akBottom] = [akTop]) then
            NewRange := Max(NewRange, Position + Control.Top + Control.Height);
        alBottom: Inc(AlignMargin, Control.Height);
      end;
  end;
```

As you can see a control will not have an effect on an automatic vertical scroll bar if it doesn't have either `alTop`, `alBottom` or `alNone` alignment. Yours have `alCustom`.

This is also why overriding autosizing behavior won't help, `AutoSize` depends on controls having "left", "right", "top", "bottom" or "none" aligned controls.

You have to redesign your control taking into consideration how VCL internally works. Not all of the internal dependency aspects can be documented, so you have to use the *source* for this kind of *enhanced* development.